# how can segmentation fault error be fixed OpenCV python

Tags: python, opencv, pytorch, yolov5

I am trying to run a simple objection detection on webcam using Yolov5 but I keep getting the error below.

> > zsh: segmentation fault

The camera appears to open then shut off immediately and the code exit with the above error.
Here is my code

```
def object_detector():
    DEVICE = "cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu" 
    model = torch.hub.load('ultralytics/yolov5', 'yolov5s')
    # mmocr = MMOCR(det='TextSnake', recog='SAR')
    cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    
    while(True): 
        ret, frame = cam.read()

        # ocr_result = mmocr.readtext(frame, output='demo/cam.jpg', export='demo/', print_result=True, imshow=True)
        # print("RESULT \n ", ocr_result)

        frame = frame[:, :, [2,1,0]]
        frame = Image.fromarray(frame) 
        frame = cv2.cvtColor(np.array(frame), cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)

        # ocr_result = mmocr.readtext(frame, output='demo/cam.jpg', export='demo/', print_result=True, imshow=True)
        # print("RESULT \n ", ocr_result)
        result = model(frame,size=640)
        # Results
        # crops = result.crop(save=True)
        cv2.imshow('YOLO', np.squeeze(result.render()))
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break
    
    cam.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

what am i doing wrong and how can i fix it ?

Comment: have you tried the

try:

except:


to catch the error

Comment: [mre] required. figure out what's irrelevant to reproducing the issue, and remove that.

Answer (score 0):

You're not testing the return value from `cam.read()` ensure that `ret` is a success code, and that `frame` is not a nullptr before you proceed.

Comment: could you write the code correction?

Answer (score 0):

You need to check that an image is returned in the first place. The first return resulting from `cam.read()` tells you whether an image has been received. This is how you can make use of it:

```
...
while(True): 
    ret, frame = cam.read()
    if ret:
        frame = frame[:, :, [2,1,0]] 
        ...
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
cam.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```